# .htaccess - remove html extension and trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some problems with my .htaccess. I want to remove .html file extension from url, but what I also want is to remove slash at the end of the url. This is my current .htaccess configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Apache Rewrite Rules
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /dev

    # Redirects request for url ending in a /:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes .html extension from url
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html
</IfModule>
```

And my problem is that if I go to my homepage http://example.com/dev (dev is temporary directory for now) then slash is automatically added at the end of the url, which results in http://example.com/dev/. If I go to some other page, let's say http://example.com/contact page loads correctly, but when I enter the url with slash at the end, then redirects me to http://example/contact (in root directory) instead of just remove trailing slash. I'm not .htaccess master, so I would really appreciate some help on this one.

Comment: You don't need `\.`. This would work too: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html`

Comment: Pretty sure that this is mod_dir messing with the url. It will add slashes to URL's when requesting existing directories, unless you tell it to do otherwise. I think it should work correctly if you add `DirectorySlash off` before everything else. Can't test it right now though.

Comment: Disabling DirectorySlash unfortunately, doesn't work. When i try to go to http://example.com/dev I get an error messag "You don't have permission to access /dev on this server."

Comment: I think you should write 1st Rule such  `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]` without eading slash.  Because  esle rewrite don't add base to absolute path

Comment: @CookieMan but it doesn't add the slash. Without a slash, `DirectoryIndex` will not automatically load the index file of a directory. That's the downside of removing slashes behind URL's. The rest of the problem is solved by what splash says.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yeah, ok, seems like everything works when I move files to root directory. But can you tell me why while I have my site in dev subfolder and I enter url example.com/dev/contact/ i am redirected to example.com/contact and ofc getting 404 error. Can I temporary fix it somehow?

Comment: Because of what splash says: If you rewrite to `/$1` you rewrite to an absolute path, relative to the root. It will ignore the RewriteBase. Since you used a permanent redirect in testing, you'll need to clear your cache completely before you'll see any change regarding redirects.

Comment: Cache problem indeed ) Thanks for help.

Comment: @CookieMan, so as a result - does it work? :)